# What was Newton's statement of the universal law of gravitation?

Tags: physics, newton, gravity

Newton explained the inverse square law in *Principia*. On looking through an English translation, though, I'm having difficulty pulling out a single quote that is Newton's clearest statement of the idea that point particles attracts all point particles with a force that is inversely proportional to the square of the distance and proportional to each of the masses.

I see proofs of the shell theorem that state that the force between a point and a sphere obeys this law, and I see proofs that if we start by assuming an inverse square law, we get conic section orbits. But the book is very large and difficult to read; I simply can't find the best passage stating the universal gravitational law in Newton's own words. What is the best passage to use?

Answer (score 3):

Chrandrasekhar's [*Newton's* Principia *for the Common Reader*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=4189) p. 370:

> ### 104. Proposition VII: the universal law of gravitation
>
> We have now reached the climactic point of *Philosphie naturalis Principia Mathematica*. After establishing the preceding propositions, particularly, Propositions IV and VI, Newton, at long last, is ready to enunciate his law of gravitation. Let him speak.
>
> > *Proposition VII. Theorem VII*
> > *That there is a power of gravity pertaining to all bodies, proportional to the several quantities of matter which they contain.*

Comment: That doesn't seem to mention the inverse square law.

Comment: @MarkEichenlaub It is mentioned in [Corollary 2 to Proposition V](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Mathematical_Principles_of_Natural_Philosophy_(1846)/BookIII-Prop1), but only for planets rather than all bodies:"*The force of gravity which tends to any one planet is reciprocally as the square of the distance of places from that planet's centre*". Proposition VII then extends it to all bodies and adds the proportionality to their masses.